# Disabling optimization in javac?

Tags: optimization, javac

I'm writing my own copy of the JVM and would like to test its behavior on some simple numeric operations, such as additions, subtractions, numeric overflow, etc.  Rather than writing the bytecode by hand, I thought it would be a good idea to just write plain Java code, have `javac` compile it down to bytecode, and then test the JVM on that bytecode.

The problem is that `javac` is making a lot of (very sensible!) inline optimizations that prevent the code from testing what I'd like it to test.  For example, one test tries to verify that integral overflows are handled correctly for all types.  Here's one snapshot:

```
byte min = (byte)-128;
byte max = (byte) 127;

assertTrue((byte)(max + 1) == min); // Should overflow and work correctly.
```

The generated `.class` file has the result of `((byte)max + 1)` hardcoded as `(byte) -128`, which completely defeats the point of the test.

My question is this: **is there a way to disable optimization in `javac`**?  I haven't been able to find a command-line switch to do this, though perhaps I just haven't looked hard enough.  If there is no way to do this, is there another Java compiler that does have the ability to compile with all optimizations turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many production compilers, including the common Sun-derived `javac`, do that sort of simplification no matter what optimization is set to.

Have you looked at [Jasmin](http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/), the Java bytecode 'assembler'?

Comment: I have not heard of Jasmin!  That's a pretty cool link.  I may have to investigate this.

Answer (score 3):

I think most of the *optimizations* you seem to think of are actually mandated by the JLS, as these are [constant expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.28). So, make sure you don't have constant expressions, and javac can't optimize them away.

In your example, you may write it like this:

```
byte min = new Byte((byte)-128).byteValue();
byte max = new Byte((byte) 127).byteValue();

assertTrue((byte)(max + 1) == min); // Should overflow and work correctly.
```

Comment: This is a solution to a problem which doesn’t exist. Since neither `min` nor `max` are `final`, these variables are not compile-time constants. If they were, the compiler would have to evaluate the entire expression `(byte)(max + 1) == min` at compile time and produce the equivalent of `assertTrue(true)`. So in either case, with compile-time constants or non-constant variables, the OP can’t have seen an inlined result of `(byte)(max + 1)` in the bytecode.